# Cannot insert the value NULL into column - how to force identity to increment?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

When attempting to `INSERT` into my table I'm getting the following exception:

> Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Line 17
> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'rrrId', table 'rrr.rrrColumns'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

Here's my `INSERT`:

```
INSERT INTO [rrr].[rrrColumns]([Header],[FormElementId])
VALUES ('F2','2F0B9649-2AF7-4C6E-9A0B-02C2C8FE7BB8')
```

The table designer shows that it is indeed an identity specification:

[image]

Here's the full table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE [rrr].[rrrColumns](
    [rrrColumnId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [rrrId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Header] [nvarchar](256) NOT NULL,
    [FormElementId] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [BaseObjectColumnName] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_rrrColumns] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [rrrColumnId] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [rrr].[rrrColumns]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_rrrColumns_FormElements] FOREIGN KEY([FormElementId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[FormElements] ([FormElementId])
GO

ALTER TABLE [rrr].[rrrColumns] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_rrrColumns_FormElements]
GO

ALTER TABLE [rrr].[rrrColumns]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_rrrColumns_rrrs] FOREIGN KEY([rrrId])
REFERENCES [rrr].[rrrs] ([rrrId])
GO

ALTER TABLE [rrr].[rrrColumns] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_rrrColumns_rrrs]
GO
```

**How do we `INSERT` into this table without specifying the identity?**

Comment: `[rrrId] [int] NOT NULL,` This column is NOT an identity column. You MUST provide a value when inserted. Where does that come from? No one can say without knowledge of your schema, how it is used, and your code.

Comment: You have two columns that have id in their name
The first  [rrrColumnId]  is the Pk and it is IDENTITY
second [rrrId] why?
You must pass a value For [rrrId]  in the insert statement

Comment: Are these column names contrived or the *actual* names used in production? It seems like the lack of meaningful names probably contribute to your oversight.

Answer (score 1):

It's the `rrrColumnId` column which is the identity column.

The error you are getting is refering to the column `rrrId` which does not accept NULLS and you are not specifying any value for it in the insert statement, hence the error

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column '**rrrId**'